# Detect if the app is Game or not Android

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I have a AccessibilityService in my app. When a app comes to the forground, i am trying to detect it and its type. So basically if the app is game, i will do some database staffs. But i am unable to detect if the running app is game or not.

**My Service code:**

```
@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
            if (event.getPackageName() != null && event.getClassName() != null) {
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                        event.getPackageName().toString(),
                        event.getClassName().toString()
                );

                ActivityInfo activityInfo = tryGetActivity(componentName);
                boolean isActivity = activityInfo != null;
                if (isActivity) {

                    if ((activityInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "system");
                    } else {




                        // For Opening
                        if ((activityInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_IS_GAME) == ApplicationInfo.FLAG_IS_GAME) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "Playing games");
                            AppInfo.updateAppInfo(componentName.getPackageName(), new Date(), true, Utlis.AppType.GAME);
                        } 


                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private ActivityInfo tryGetActivity(ComponentName componentName) {
        try {
            return getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(componentName, 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is a problem? What you expect it to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: for games i am expecting to execute this line ... Log.v(TAG, "Playing games");

Comment: but it doesnt work

Comment: on which Android version you try?

Comment: its oreo (one plus 3t)

Comment: probably that is because `FLAG_IS_GAME` is deprecated. Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo#FLAG_IS_GAME

Comment: Do you know any other way of detecting the category of the app?